# How to Return MEDIA URL in Template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I Create This Function to return a **Media URL** of a File in **Templates** but it Show in HTML like **[http://example.com/history/('/media/exam/returns/files.png',)](http://example.com/history/(%27/media/exam/returns/files.png%27,))**

```
    @property
    def ReturnAttachment(self):
        from ResultManagement.models import Result
        attachment = Result.objects.filter(examinee=self.examinee, exam=self.exam)
        attachment_url = attachment[0].attachment.url
        if self.hasReturnAttachment():
            #print("URL", attachment)
            return attachment_url,
```

How can I fix it?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Remove the comma at the end, in `return attachment_url`.

Answer (score 0):

The object is wrapped in a singleton tuple by the trailing comma at the end. You thus should remove the comma at the end of the `return attachment_url` line:

```
@property
def ReturnAttachment(self):
    if self.hasReturnAttachment():
        from ResultManagement.models import Result
        attachment = Result.objects.filter(examinee=self.examinee, exam=self.exam)
        attachment_url = attachment[0].attachment.url
        return attachment_url
```